# The search box on /questions/tagged/foo is counter-intuitive

Tags: feature-request, search, new-nav

When clicking on a tag, you arrive at a search page with the filter set to that tag.

Time and time again, I make the mistake of further narrowing my search by typing in **(1)**, but that search box only accepts tags and auto converts words to tags. Instead, I have to type in **(2)**.

[image: screenshot]

It seems counter-intuitive that the large search box in the centre offers less functionality than the small search box in the top right corner.

Can the behaviour of the large search box be changed to accept regular words, and not auto convert everything to a tag?

Comment: I already trained myself to always add an extra search parameter like is:q or closed:no in the search box so I end up on the proper search page, not on the tag page....

Comment: This must be some kind of special voodoo that you're doing, because it doesn't happen for me. It is hard to imagine a well-designed page ever having *two different search boxes*.

Comment: @CodyGray what happens for you when you type in the large search box?

Comment: I do not have a large search box. The only search box I have is the normal one in the upper-right. One search box ought to be enough for anyone!

Comment: @CodyGray try clicking on a tag for this question, e.g. [meta-tag:feature-request]. You should see a page like the one in the screenshot. Unless this is some profile setting or A/B testing?

Comment: It turns out to be a feature of [the new navigation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814).